# How to redirect Mediaserver log message to logcat in android

Tags: android, media, logcat

I want to see the log message of Mediaserver in Android, I have opened the logcat, but I can't see anything from Mediaserver. Mediaserver itself is a service that start with system boot from `init.rc`, the problem now is, I can't modify the init.rc.

It is said the log of service are direct to /dev/null, that is why we can't see the log. 
Also, they suggest to use service to redirect the log to logwrapper that we can see the log with logcat. I have tried by the command `"service mediaserver /system/bin/logwrapper /system/bin/mediaserver`", but it not works.

Do you have some good method to get the log from mediaserver? And moreover, could you show me a better way to debug mediaserver?
    Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mediaserver is basically just a host for 4 other services
AudioFlinger, MediaPlayerService, CameraService, and AudioPolicyService (I'm looking at ICS 4.0.3 source code here)

You may want to look at which of these services you are trying to instrument... Keep in mind that most of LOGV and LOGD are suppressed when they are compiled for release